# Can´t understand error from Xcode while building

Tags: xcode8, macos-sierra

I am trying to build my project after updating xcode to 8.3.2 and macos sierra to 10.12.4.

Xcode is throwing me this error:

> Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
>   Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ld:'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'library'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'not'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'found'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'for'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'clang:'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'error:'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'linker'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'command'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'failed'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'with'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'exit'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'code'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '1'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '(use'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'to'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'see'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'invocation)'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ld:'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'library'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'not'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'found'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'for'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'clang:'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'error:'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'linker'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'command'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'failed'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'with'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'exit'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'code'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '1'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '(use'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'to'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'see'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'invocation)'
```

I can´t understand the problem.

I think that it could be an error from a library but i don´t know how to find that library, I also think that could be a bug from xcode.

I am using cocoapods which are:

```
pod 'DACircularProgress'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.8'
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'INTULocationManager'
  pod 'TWRCharts'
  pod 'EFCircularSlider', '~> 0.2.0'
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Tried the first-aid things? (Cleaned the project, restarted Xcode, removed pods & re-added them?)

Comment: I have done that a lot of times and didn´t work

Answer (score 0):

Try This Brother

> Pod deintegrate

> Pod Install

> Pod Update